How to remove multiple items from a dict of lists while keeping the lists in sync in Python
My question is not a duplicate of Remove elements from several lists simultaneously because the top solution of the linked question uses a for loop to delete items while iterating over it which I have already mentioned in my question that it doesn't work and is already documented behaviour. The accepted answer in the linked question uses numpy which is an additional package that shouldn't be needed in order to perform basic task such as rearranging data structures like lists

I have a dict of lists that I maintain which in essence functions like a spreadsheet row. Every item on the same index of the lists belongs to the same record. The use of this is to keep track of open transactions and every once in a while, remove the items which are closed.
This is the initial state.
closed_pos = {
     "TransactionID": [],
     "Item":[],
     "BuyPrice":[],
     "SellPrice":[]
}

live_pos = {
    "TransactionID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "Status": ["Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Closed"],
    "Item": ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"],
    "BuyPrice": [5, 10, 15, 20, 5],
    "SellPrice": [None, 12, None, 25, 7],
}

Now I want to move the transactions which are closed periodically. The reason for doing this is simple. The live_pos is accessed more frequently and is therefore helpful if I can lighten the load on it.
The problem is I can't reliably remove items from a list that I am iterating over which is a well documented behaviour.
One solution that could work is that I iterate over the list and keep a separate list of all indexes to remove. Reverse the list indexes_to_remove and then use append-pop to get the desired behaviour without messing with placements of items while I move the closed transactions
indexes_to_remove = []

for i in range(len(live_pos["TransactionID"])):
#Make a list of all indexes of lists to remove
    if live_pos["Status"][i] == "Closed":
        indexes_to_remove.append(i)

indexes_to_remove.reverse()
#Reverse the list so that you can use .pop() without problems.

for index in indexes_to_remove:
#remove items by index and feed them in closed_pos

        closed_pos["TransactionID"].append(live_pos["TransactionID"].pop(index))
        live_pos["Status"].pop(index) # No need to append `Status` to closed_pos. It is always going to be `Closed`
        closed_pos["Item"].append(live_pos["Item"].pop(index))
        closed_pos["BuyPrice"].append(live_pos["BuyPrice"].pop(index))
        closed_pos["SellPrice"].append(live_pos["SellPrice"].pop(index))

print(live_pos)
print(closed_pos)


This works, but the resulting closed_pos is also reversed. Instead of result being in order of 2, 4, 5, it is going to be in 5, 4, 2.
result_live_pos = {
    "TransactionID": [1, 3],
    "Status": ["Open", "Open"],
    "Item": ["ABC", "GHI"],
    "BuyPrice": [5, 15],
    "SellPrice": [None, None],
}


result_closed_pos = {
    "TransactionID": [5, 4, 2],
    "Item": ["MNO", "JKL", "DEF"],
    "BuyPrice": [5, 20, 10],
    "SellPrice": [7, 25, 12],
}

This is the result I am expecting
closed_pos = {
    "TradeID": [2, 4, 5],
    "Item": ["DEF", "JKL", "MNO"],
    "BuyPrice": [10, 20, 5],
    "SellPrice": [12, 25, 7],
}

live_pos = {
    "TradeID": [1, 3],
    "Status": ["Open", "Open"],
    "Item": ["ABC", "GHI"],
    "BuyPrice": [5, 15],
    "SellPrice": [None, None],
}


Use a better data structure (list of objects, not dictionary of lists), then this is trivial.

Don't reverse the lists, process the indices in descending order.

@mkrieger1 That's exactly what I have done. I just reversed the list which contained the indexes to delete. I have not reversed the lists which contain data. The reason was simple, reversing the indexes_to_remove  meant that the indexes of the list wouldn't change from under me while removing items

Then you need to reverse the results, or build them in the reverse order.

@mkrieger1 Reversing the results will work only the first time this code is run. As mentioned, I want to run this code periodically. If I reverse the results each time, it is not going to work. eg let's say I reversed it in the end as well and the resulting closed_pos is 2,4,5. What happens on the subsquent runs when 6,7 has to be appended to the closed_pos. The intermediate result will be 2,4,5,7,6 and final result will be  6,7,5,4,2 which will completely mess up the ordering

Just going forwards...
i = 0
while i < len(live_pos["Status"]):
    if live_pos["Status"][i] == "Closed":
        del live_pos["Status"][i]
        for k, a in closed_pos.items():
            a.append(live_pos[k].pop(i))
    else:
        i += 1

Attempt This Online!

Its not about synchronous usage, not about reversing, but about the way you append data.
You just have to use .insert(index of last item+1,data) in place of .append(data):
indexes_to_remove = []

for i in range(len(live_pos["TransactionID"])):
#Make a list of all indexes of lists to remove
    if live_pos["Status"][i] == "Closed":
        indexes_to_remove.append(i)

indexes_to_remove.reverse()
#Reverse the list so that you can use .pop() without problems.

lastindex=len(closed_pos["Item"])
for index in indexes_to_remove:
#remove items by index and feed them in closed_pos
        closed_pos["TransactionID"].insert(lastindex,live_pos["TransactionID"].pop(index))
        live_pos["Status"].pop(index) # No need to append `Status` to closed_pos. It is always going to be `Closed`
        closed_pos["Item"].insert(lastindex,live_pos["Item"].pop(index))
        closed_pos["BuyPrice"].insert(lastindex,live_pos["BuyPrice"].pop(index))
        closed_pos["SellPrice"].insert(lastindex,live_pos["SellPrice"].pop(index))

print(live_pos)
print(closed_pos)

To a bit of data math to know why it works.

def filter_dict_lists_inplace(data, condition):
    indices_to_remove = [i for i, a in enumerate(data['A']) if condition(a)]
    for idx in sorted(indices_to_remove, reverse=True):
        for lst in data.values():
            del lst[idx]
    return data

data = {
'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
'C': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'v']
}
result = filter_dict_lists_inplace(data, lambda x: x > 3)
print(result)

